# PropertyGrid drawing anomalies in .net Framework 3.5 version

Tags: .net, propertygrid

Firstly, I have to use .net framework 3.5. I think the newer versions may be better. I am trying to implement a dark theme for this control. On some of the automatic drop downs (e.g. when the property is boolean or an enum), the drop downs look shockingly bad:

[image]

TextRenderingHint in this instance is a Framework enum. You'll notice all of the white lines (the drop-down extends over the "Alignment" category header). Buttons are also rendered automatically with a 3D border and I need it to be flatstyle rather than standard (which renders the 3D border):

[image]

I know I can do custom UITypeEditors - but would rather avoid the hassle, because I've got a lot of properties + property types + the system UITypeEditors are helpful.

Is there any way to override aspects of the drawing of the items of the property gird (like you can with toolstrips etc)?

Comment: The Winforms property grid was never really meant to be customized like that.

Comment: The customization of the MSPG is limited. Just in case you need it, you could try Smart PropertyGrid which allows many customizations. Disclaimer: I'm its author. https://visualhint.com/propertygrid

Comment: Thanks. In the end, I just went with custom UITypeEditors